# Number of solutions of an indefinite equation.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations

today I'll begin my post with the following image. It is form *Combinatorial problems in Mathematical competitions* by **Yao Zhang**, I'm trying to understand this topic which I consider to be great interesting, though it's still sorta hard for me.
[image]

Here as you can see there is a proof by bars of the nonnegative solutions of the equation $ x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots + x_{m} = n $ when $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$,. I think that the explanations are clear but is there a thing that really doesn't fit at all for me.

The **corollary** says that if we change the initial condition from $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ to $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\ge m$ then the number of solutions turns to $ \dbinom{n-1}{m-1} $.

Ok! but wait a second, first of all:

1. How could you understand the given condition $ m \ge m$ I mean, combinatorially speaking how could that be interpreted in order to make a strategy to come with the solution.

And secondly,

2. What is the point of setting the variables $ y_{i} = x_{i} - 1 $ and furthermore what does the equations $\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_{i} = n $ and $\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_{i} = n-m $ have ultimately the same number of solutions?

I'm kind off lost in these matters, would someone please help me to understand with a little more detail please?
If any, thanks a lot for your time, that really helps me (:

Comment: In the first version, each of the variables $x_1,\dots,x_m$ is a **nonnegative integer**. For the corollary, the variables are instead chosen to be **positive integers**. This is the key difference, not the $n\ge m$ part. Note that if $x_i$ is an arbitrary positive integer, then $x_i-1$ is an arbitrary nonnegative integer. This is what allows us to relate the corollary to the original problem via the $y_i=x_i-1$ trick.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really notice about the differences between nonnegative integers and positive integers.

Comment: "The **corollary** says that if we change the initial condition from $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ to $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\ge m$ then the number of solutions turns to $ \dbinom{n-1}{m-1} $." :  This is wrong.  It should say that if you change the constraint from each $x_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$ to each $x_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}$, then the number of solutions...

Comment: Basically the same @MikeEarnest said, I get the point where I was wrong, thanks you all, today I've learned something new (:

Comment: "How could you understand the given condition $ m \ge m$" : I am guessing that you intend here "...$m \geq n$.  That is, you are wondering how you can have an equation like, what are all the non-negative solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 2$?  This is feasible precisely because the variables $x_1, \cdots, x_4$ are allowed to equal $(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The important condition is not $n \ge m$, rather it is *positive solutions* to the indefinite equation. So the question is, how many *positive* integer solutions are there to $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m=n$. We already know the number of non negative solutions to this equation. So let's try to convert this problem of positive solutions into one of non negative solutions.

See that for positive solutions in $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m=n$, we have $x_i \gt 0$.
So let $x_i=y_i+1$. This way, $y_i \ge 0$ and we have $y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_m=n-m$
and those two have the exact same number of solutions because they are the exact same equation.

Comment: Now, everything seems cleaner